# Implementing jquery UI Datepicker inside Reactjs

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to implement jQuery UI datepicker Inside Reactjs. Everything seems fine ,i am able to select the date from the datepicker. The problem is i am running a function on  **onChange** event of the input,that function is not triggering.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="example" ></div>

 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.min.js" ></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/babel">

  var DatePicker = React.createClass({
      _destroyDatePicker: function(){
          var element = this.refs.input;
          $(element).datepicker('destroy');
      },
      _initDatePicker: function(){
          var element = this.refs.input;
          $(element).datepicker(this.props);    
      },
      componentDidMount: function(){
          this._initDatePicker();
      },
         componentWillUnmount: function(){
          this._destroyDatePicker();
      },
      render: function() {
          return <input ref="input" type="text" onChange={(evt)=>console.log('new date', evt.target.value)} {...this.props}/>
      }
  });

  ReactDOM.render(<DatePicker defaultValue="05/30/2017" />, document.getElementById('example'));
 
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: React and jQuery aren't really supposed to be meshed together, as React constructs a virtual DOM representation for synthetic events. Have you considered any of the existing React component libraries for date picking? A simple Google search for "react date picker" should get you many different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding jquery Ui doesnt help me but, i have able to implement a [datetimepicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) plugin with react and it works perfectly

```
var ReactDatePicker = React.createClass({
_initDatePicker: function () {
    var $this = this;
    var element = this.refs.input;
    $(element).datetimepicker({
        timepicker: false,
        format: 'Y/m/d',
        onChangeDateTime: this._updateDate
    });
},
_updateDate: function () {
     console.log("new value ",this.refs.input.value);
},
_destroyDatePicker:function(){
    var element = this.refs.input;
    $(element).datetimepicker('destroy');
},
componentDidMount:function(){
    this._initDatePicker();
},
componentDidUpdate: function () {
    this._initDatePicker();
},
componentWillUnmount: function () {
    this._destroyDatePicker();
},
render: function() {
    return <input ref="input" value={this.props.value} type="text"/>
   }})
```